# Can you use and/or together in a Query function on google sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match, google-query-language

I am trying to use the below function which works when "not" is removed.

```
QUERY(Sheet!A:L,"SELECT A,G,H,I,J,K WHERE F='City' AND H='model' AND I>=Number AND (not C contains 'AA1' or not C Contains 'AB1')",1)
```

Comment: It seems to work OK (assuming Number is defined). Can you give us an example where it doesn't work plz?

Comment: The full formula is really large and I would like to exclude about 25 different vehicle models being pulled. =QUERY(SheetA:L,"SELECT A,G,H,I,J,K WHERE F='City' AND H='Sedan' AND I>=2016 AND (not C contains 'BMW 3 series' or not C Contains 'Audi A4'",1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can test with matches and regex. if it still not working for you then the dataset is insufficient.

```
=QUERY(Sheet!A:L,
 "SELECT A,G,H,I,J,K 
  WHERE F='City' 
    AND H='model' 
    AND I>=Number 
    AND not C matches 'AA1|AB1'", 1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You are a legend.

Answer (score 1):

Just a postscript to this, if you did want to use Contains it should be

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:L,"SELECT A,G,H,I,J,K WHERE F='City' AND H='Sedan' AND I>=2016 AND not (C contains 'BMW 3 series' or C Contains 'Audi A4')",1)
```

Your original formula would only exclude a row that contained both BMW 3 series and Audi A4 because

```
(not C contains 'BMW 3 series' or not C Contains 'Audi A4'",1)
```

is equivalent to

```
not (C contains 'BMW 3 series' and C Contains 'Audi A4'",1)
```

by [de Morgan's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

So given the following data

[image]

Your formula would retrieve

[image]

while the correct result is

[image]